# Issues with setParent Google Drive Picker

Tags: php, google-drive-api, picker

I'm pretty stuck with using the Google Drive Picker.

I've followed the standard docs and I have a working implementation of the following:

- Authenticate to a GDrive user (in this case, my own)
- Upload an item selected through the Picker to the root of my GDrive

However, I have a specific use case - I'm a lecturer and I want to allow my students to submit their work to me (which could be anything from a text document to a multi-gig mp4 file). So, I will always authenticate agaisnt my own GDrive account as that is where I want the files to end up.

Furthermore, I want to be able to grab a user authentication (e.g. student inputs username and password that is checked against outside DB) to then funnel the submitted work to a specific folder, tied to their ID, that I have created on my GDrive account.

So, say a user with username aa001 logged in, I then check against the value for their GDrive folder ID and inject that into the picker setParent so that the files they upload go into that folder.

Well, that's how its supposed to work!

If I try this, I always get a server rejected error. Checked in Chrome and Safari, neither work. Please see attached screenshots of API details and source code.

Any ideas? I've read that there is an issue using oAuth for this but noone has proposed a solution to get round the bug.

Images:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqt0js7gmyk0gk9/Archive.zip?dl=0

Code:
http://pastebin.com/gJCyhqCS

(sorry for pastebin etc but not enough rep to post properly)

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

What if you flipped your logic around:
1) student authenticates
2) launch picker to browse the student's Drive account
3) student selects their work from their drive account
4) if you are using drive.file scope, use the Sharing Dialog widget to allow the student to share the file with your account
4) Upon successful sharing, the file ID they picked is sent to your php script
5) your php script has a refresh token for your Drive account. It then moves the student's file into whatever folder you want to place the student's work in

Something like that...

Comment: Thanks! Only problem is, not every student has GDrive, and we are not able to _force_ them to get a GDrive account. (I'm in the UK, so we still have some backwards facing people who think that nothing is secure on the cloud/everything should be on floppy disks/etc). Another issue is that some students are very tech illiterate - they can barely handle email, so anything that would require them to sign up for an external service and then figure out where files lived between their PC and GDrive would be an issue. Sorry to sound negative - it's a great idea - but won't work for us at the moment.

Comment: PS I would upvote to say thanks but not enough rep :(

Comment: No problem :-). Then you will probably need to handle everything yourself serverside using the php client. A student would upload to your server, then your server would turn around and upload to your gdrive.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I am at the moment. Server appears to be choking on any upload currently, gotta check with the provider if they have enabled PHP uploads properly! Thanks for the advice.